# Write BSON Document to a File

Tags: c#, mongodb

How can I write all the data in a collection to an external text file? The following is the collection:

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("clicks");
```

Comment: What research have you done?  What have you tried already?

Comment: I have tried this: 
            string data = collection.ToJson<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>();
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\data.txt", json);

Comment: Add that information to your question, including what happened when you tried it and what you were expecting

Comment: Agreed with @Taegost, next time try to add to your question relevant info like the code you have so far, the current result, the result you are expecting. That would help to understand better what is your issue and in what step you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I suppose you want to save your collection in json format. If that is the case, you can do something like this:

```
var r = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();// Load all documents of that collection
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("file.txt",// path where you want to save the result
                             r.Aggregate<BsonDocument,string>("",(seed,document)=>seed+document.ToString()+"\n"));
```

If your collection have a lot of documents, you might consider to use an `StringBuilder` due to performance reasons:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
r.ForEach(d => builder.Append(d.ToString()+"\n"));
File.WriteAllText("file.txt",// path where you want to save the result
                  builder.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks that all I wanted :), can you also suggest me how to make the results in the text file nicer?